# How to remove "SDL Tridion has not been tested with this version of the browser"

Tags: tridion

I'm seeing the following message in the Tridion CME and am unsure of where the configuration is to that removes it.

Can anybody help?

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This means that you are using an **unsupported browser**, or **unsupported version**.

If you want to avoid receiving this message when using an unsupported version you can modify the file `\web\webui\webroot\configuration\system.config`

In this file you need to add your desired browser into the `<supportedbrowsers>` node

***UPDATE:***

As stated on the comments, your team need to be aware that they are working on an **unsupported** version, even if the popup does not remind it for you. 
As a rule of thumb, if the GUI seems broken or buggy on any specific action, retest against a supported version.

**TIP:** To overcome the problem of updating the system.config with every new version. (It's hard to keep pace nowadays with new chrome of firefox versions!) you can use regular expressions:

```xml
<supportedbrowsers>
    <browser name="Any Mozilla Firefox" regExp="Firefox/.*"/>
    <browser name="Any Google Chrome" regExp="Chrome/.*"/>
    ...
</supportedbrowsers>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that it won't magically make the browser version be supported now, only that it will stop the message from appearing, and the message will be back once your browsers get updated again.

Answer (score 3):

Easy "removal". Ensure you make note the the **client** that you've removed a note from a **supported point of view**. Annoying as a developer indeed. A reminder to an - unsupported - client when you leave is really important.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should not try to ignore the message. Try to find out the right supported browser based on version of your SDL Tridion and please note you make need to so some browser settings as well.

Comment: Sensible advice, although the problem I can see is that some browsers are updated so frequently, e.g. Firefox & Chrome, that it could be difficult to stay on a supported version of these browsers.

Comment: Yes I agree this seems to be because of verison of these browsers.